# jquery autocomplete pop up on click multiple words

Tags: jquery

Can some one help me on adding pop up effect on click to this jquery autocomplete? I was able to add using

```
.bind('focus', function () {
    $(this).autocomplete("search");
```

But it doesn't work with this multiple word one. so how do I add a pop up effect for the below code ? any help would be appreciated.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Multiple values</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
var availableTags = [
  "ActionScript",
  "AppleScript",
  "Asp",
  "BASIC",
  "C",
  "C++",
  "Clojure",
  "COBOL",
  "ColdFusion",
  "Erlang",
  "Fortran",
  "Groovy",
  "Haskell",
  "Java",
  "JavaScript",
  "Lisp",
  "Perl",
  "PHP",
  "Python",
  "Ruby",
  "Scala",
  "Scheme"
 ];
 function split( val ) {
  return val.split( /,\s*/ );
}
function extractLast( term ) {
  return split( term ).pop();
}

$( "#tags" )
  // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
  .bind( "foucus", function( event ) {
    if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
        $( this ).data( "ui-autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  })
  .autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: function( request, response ) {
      // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
      response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
        availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
    },
    focus: function() {
      // prevent value inserted on focus
      return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
      var terms = split( this.value );
      // remove the current input
      terms.pop();
      // add the selected item
      terms.push( ui.item.value );
      // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
      terms.push( "" );
      this.value = terms.join( ", " );
      return false;
    }
  });
  });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <div class="ui-widget">
 <label for="tags">Tag programming languages: </label>
 <input id="tags" size="50" />
 </div>


 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `on input` event. It works well for me

```
$('#tags').on('input', function() {
  $(this).autocomplete("search");
});
```

Comment: what do you mean with "multiple words" ?

Comment: look at the above code, I mean like when you type for ex php then autocomplete will show you the match and you select it and if you want to choose again like java you can. Shortly you can select multiple values(words) on one input field separated by comma.